# Dialog flow Error Could not find a RichResponse or SystemIntent in the platform response

Tags: dialogflow-es

I recive follwoing response when i test my agent on Google action simulator

Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of invalid platform response: Could not find a RichResponse or SystemIntent in the platform response for agentId: c4591986-48d2-40d2-99e1-17d4a58994b8 and intentId: 57a7dd9d-6bd6-494e-b091-270db5c2394e. WebhookStatus: ."

I am sending follwing custom payload on default channel and using same default on google action

Comment: can you share the code u tried